# Must nested mapped types implement all patterns of children indexes?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

This nested mapped types code below doesn't work as I expected.

```
type Test = { 
  [slasher in `/${string}`]: {
    [method in 'POST' | 'GET']: {
      parameter: unknown
    }
  }
}

type ExtendedTest = { 
  '/slash': {
    'POST': {
      parameter: unknown
    }
  }
}

const Tester = <T extends Test>() => {
}

Tester<ExtendedTest>()
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Type 'ExtendedTest' does not satisfy the constraint 'Test'.   Property
> ''/slash'' is incompatible with index signature.
>     Property 'GET' is missing in type '{ POST: { parameter: unknown; }; }' but required in type '{ GET: { parameter: unknown; }; POST: {
> parameter: unknown; }; }'.
```

I thought union types in mapped types' indexes only needs at least one index of them in extended types.
I understood that I must implement all patterns of union types as indexes but what occurs this kind of error?

P.S.
What I'd like to realize is to create a ExtendedTest type with POST(or GET) only by extending the Test type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `K in "GET" | "POST"` is really just a loop when defining a type's keys/values. To make it only allow you to specify either `"GET" | "POST"` and not both, you can do some TypeScript black magic by looping through all the keys and then creating a new object that makes the other values optional & forced to be `undefined`.  Here is [a snippet of the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwPIDsKoGYB4AqUEAHsBOgCYDOUiARgFYQDGwAfFALwBQUUA3rz5QA2lADSUAJbooAawghE2KIQC6ALigB6bVCSIwUYAAsATogCuAcxNQAhgnmKqQ4QNHiATNNkBRYmY4SwoIXAUlFXwAGgk2NQB+LUtKCGwZCAooAF8dPQBbewUHJ0RTCDNnEBoSMDgpZilgOBAoFND0zAptQ2ApRHRHN3coADIPEQB9XwlNVRFxNRy8qELi8qhmSzMzcmAq7QA3R0toDap7fIghXJIyShoZbAqoABIV5l37MmNwaEcpPZXO4Em8RBFlG8lrooNYIPtjsEIDQABQpfqySFgRBUKhSOhwaD0JisKgASmGWkwhwqAG5uNwYfgABIASQAylAAMKoABKvL8XPwABkAJpQABiMFZwvZjL0zAGVH2ZGVAEYtPAkGhMDhcPwHFpgGZTrE6EaTdBshxOB57BbTVBzcZLTl6fLVGzOTz+YKReKAAowdnsvxyxXoZXGZHALyahAoDBYPAG+0ux3O42nHI2jyZ13Zd2gSCqGNcARCKYzAAG2le-GVZhk1my1bmWsTupTommMigACIAOJ+fD9qAAHwHAdQ7NHcwNYHsZku8IqWns6FauWt9MLDOL0AC91CFHwZdtBqEAHJtPY6FZgFetIJ3NPZ8-hnxF8urmQzMl0DkdAUHQYZshuIR+20fsP3cYd8FgkZvxXP8AKAkCwOGJkvW5VAABE-Fw30hTFSVpVlLCACphjfBCKxGKBkN-Nc2kA4DkFA9xwPcSjtAg8DuGwFJWAxBxcQqYAz2VAgiFIchqFLZU2BRMkBAEoEqAkqTgFwI95MybTlLJWkgA) for your issue:

```
type AllowOneOf<T extends object> =
  {
    [ K in keyof T ]: // loop through all keys
      { [K2 in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: undefined } // make all other keys explicitly undefined/optional
        & { [_ in K]: T[K] } // make the current key/value the same
  } extends infer $ // create type alias
    ? $[keyof $] // get values (union of possible objects)
    : never;

// THIS CORRECTLY FAILS
// const test1: AllowOneOf<{ a: true, b: true }> = { a: true, b: true };

// THIS CORRECTLY PASSES
const test2: AllowOneOf<{ a: true, b: true }> = { b: true };

type Test = {
  [_ in `/${string}`]: AllowOneOf<{ [_ in "GET" | "POST"]: { parameter: any } }>;
};

type ExtendedTest = { 
  '/about': {
    POST: {
      parameter: unknown
    }
  }
  "/": {
    GET: {
      parameter: unknown
    }
    // THIS CODE CORRECTLY FAILS
    /*
    POST: {
      parameter: unknown
    }
    */
  }
}

function assertTest<T extends Test>() {}

assertTest<ExtendedTest>();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I'd like and it do works fine! I haven't understood the code in detail but I'm going to give myself time to understand it.

Comment: I thought it was the solution for my problem, but if I remove the GET or POST,  it shows the same error.

Comment: @Akumachan Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  Will update my answer as soon as I have time.

Comment: @Akumachan I have updated my solution and hopefully it works for you now

Comment: Thanks again, I cannot understand all the codes of them right now but it must be what I wanted! I'll try to read and understand it,